# Visual Studio Gulp Babel Resolve Imports

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, gulp, material-design, gulp-babel

How to make gulp-babel resolve the imports of a js file. Because right now it is running without error in visual studio but the imports are not resolved. Does the source directory of modules to import need to be specified - how to do that in the gulpfile.js?

gulpfile.js

```
"use strict";

 var gulp = require("gulp");
 var babel = require("gulp-babel");

 gulp.task("js", function () {
     return gulp.src('./wwwroot/js/app.js')
     .pipe(babel())
     . pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/js/babel'));
 });
```

app.js:

```
import { MDCRipple } from '@material/ripple';
import { MDCTextField } from '@material/textfield';

const username = new MDCTextField(document.querySelector('.username'));
const password = new MDCTextField(document.querySelector('.password'));

new MDCRipple(document.querySelector('.cancel'));
new MDCRipple(document.querySelector('.next'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue:

https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/247

In my current understanding the issue was: the dependencies are not being transpiled to a javascript version understandable by browserify.

[What worked]

gulpfile.js:

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp");
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var babelify = require('babelify');

gulp.task("js", function () {
    browserify('./wwwroot/js/app.js')
        .transform("babelify", {
            global: true,
            presets: ["es2015", "es2016", "stage-0"],
            ignore: /\/node_modules\/underscore/
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('babel.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/js'));
});
```

package.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "6.26.3",
        "gulp": "3.9.1",
        "browserify": "15.0.0",
        "babelify": "8.0.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-es2016": "6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
        "vinyl-source-stream": "2.0.0",
        "material-components-web": "0.28.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Browsers can't handle import statements, browserify bundling fixes this. However, browserify cannot read es6, so you are right. First transpile with babelify, then bundle with browserify and you get all those fancy imports very nicely!